# Добавление значка-иконки в функции mail()

Tags: иконки, php

Как при обычной отправке письма (функция mail() на PHP) приклеить к письму "shortcut icon".

Например, уведомления на почту от facebook и twitter в графе отправителя письма содержат favicon. Как это делается? Может в headers параметры необходимо задавать? Google мне тут не помог, помогите вы, please();

А еще, из любопытства, у "В Контакте" есть предзагрузка иконки - это AJAX зоголовок меняет или какие-то другие особенности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в эту сторону: [Иконки сервисов в Почте@Mail.Ru](http://api.mail.ru/docs/guides/mailicon/), [Open Mail Format](http://www.openmailformat.org/mainpage.html)

Comment: Open Mail Format написали похоже mail.ru :) Потому что никто, кроме них его не поддерживает :)
У меня вообще thunderbird и почта на gmail, так что я ничего не увижу подобного еще долго :)

Comment: Да, они и написали. :) Ну а, собственно, больше никто и не показывает значки у писем с сайтов-сервисов.
Хотя вру, у Яндекс.Почты тоже есть поддержка значков для отправителей (пруф: http://clip2net.com/s/NZuR)… И где-то я даже документацию видел, но найти сейчас не могу :(

Answer (score 0):

Насчёт иконки в письме - не знаю. Подозреваю, что это самодеятельность почтовых сайтов. В Ms Outlook, в отличие от яндекса и мейла, подобных иконок не наблюдаю. =)

Нет, с иконкой на сайте всё гораздо проще: создаётся новый элемент link со свойством rel="shortcut icon" и новым url. И заменяет собой старый элемент. Иконка, соответственно, при этом тоже изменятся.

Answer (score 0):

Никаких заголовков не может быть, нет там таких полей. Все, что есть на сайтах - это дело их рук :)

А по поводу вконтакте - можно просто урл менять у элемента link, не обязательно его пересоздавать :)

Comment: Т.е. они сами клеют иконки на знаменитые порталы?

Comment: Яндекс точно так делает) И в выдаче у яндекса тоже favicon сайт автоматически находится)